# iOS Loading full calendar into ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, calendar

We have few calendar libraries like Kal, Tapko etc. but they all present each month separately. 
Is there any way to show all months into continuous scrollView?

We can try but as calendar for say 10 years if contains tasks on everyday so its going to be pretty heavy data into UIScrollView.

So how can we solve this problem.

Main motive of asking question is to show whole calendar into continuous scrollView.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tableView`. Just make a month per cell with `reuseIdentifier`. Other will be done behind the scenes.